# Spring 3, TransactionManagement, Tomcat and changing the datasource midflight

Tags: spring, tomcat, transactions, datasource

I have a method that I've annotated with the @Transactional annotation.

The problem is, the datasource that the code runs against can change! Briefly, is it possible to change the transaction's datasource while the application is running?

In depth:
The application lets users select a database to run sql against. They can change the database at runtime. I'd like the application to run all the sql in a transaction - the sql groups are always against the same datasource, so that's not an issue.

The issue is, I don't know how to changem the transaction to use a different datasource. Varying articles have suggested the JTATransactionManager, but we're on tomcat, so no dice.

Is there a simple way to do this, or will we need to ditch the @Transactional annotation and do something else?

And if so, what is that "something else?"

Oh, the database is db2, if that's any use!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution

1. Configure all the possible datasources in spring config

   a. Datasource1 for DB1
   b. Datasource2 for DB2 etc..
2. Maintain a map of above datasource in a service class and create spring's JDBCTemplate out of selected datasource based on some key from map.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. So I do do that, but how does that help with the transaction stuff? I have the map of templates... does that mean i need a map of transactions? And how do i switch which transaction i'm using?